# jquery css() - set property to one element inside class collection

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to retain hover background color of div element, when clicking the link button. I tried with jquery and cookies. When i click on the link, jquery creates cookie that stores the index of the clicked div. Code looks like this, and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menubutton').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $.cookie('ClickedMenuBtn', index.toString(), {path: '/'});
    });
});
```

Then the second part of the code where i read the cookie value and try to set the background color of the clicked element but it does not set the color.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ClickedMenuIndex = $.cookie("ClickedMenuBtn");
    var MenuBtnIndex = parseInt(ClickedMenuIndex);
    $('.menubutton')[MenuBtnIndex].css("background-color", "rgb(242,76,15)");
});
```

It works if I remove the "[MenuBtnIndex]", but then it applys the color to all the div's that have class ".menubutton".

Comment: does `MenuBtnIndex` return the right number? Maybe instead of `$('.menubutton')[MenuBtnIndex]` try `$('.menubutton').eq(MenuBtnIndex)`

Comment: It returns the right number.

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$('.menubutton')[MenuBtnIndex]` try `$('.menubutton').eq(MenuBtnIndex)`